# which tech available for stream data from social media to hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, flume, apache-kafka, social-media

i am searching for technologies that i can use in order to stream data from social media 
to hadoop.
i searched and found those tech

1. Flume.
2. Storm.
3. Kafka.

which tool is the best? and why? does anyone familiar with some other tools ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you will want to use Flume as it is built to work with hdfs.  However, as with all things, it depends.

Kafka is basically a queuing system that is usually used to persist data in the event of a failure in your analytics architecture.  If this sounds like what you need, it might be worth looking into [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), or maybe [Kestrel](http://camel.apache.org/kestrel.html).

Storm is used for complex event processing.  If you use storm, you will be using zeroMQ under the hood, and will likely have to set up a spout that is hooked up to kafka or RabbitMQ.  IF you need to do complicated munging of the data before storage, this might be the right option.  There are other options that you can use too like [spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/).  I'm inclined to suggest storm purely out of personal preference.  I heard that linkedin was releasing a realtime complex event processing framework as well, but I can't remember the name of it.  I'll update the post when I can find it.

On a different note, if you're asking this question, it might be because you haven't built this thing yet.  If that is the case, you might want to look into something other than hadoop if you need streaming.  The ecosystem is rapidly expanding, and there are probably many ways to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) is a distributed **messaging** system. In very brief its like you pushed (published) some messages into a Kafka Queue using a KafKa producer and On the other end you consumed it using a Kafka consumer (subscriber). The messages/feeds can be divided into categories called `Topic`. Now you can run Kafka in cluster which makes it very scalable and can be expanded without any downtime.

It could be a nice choice for holding your social media streams. Kafka retains the message pushed to it for a configurable time and the best part is from their documentation they say

> *Kafka's performance is effectively constant with respect to data size so retaining lots of data is not a problem.*

Check out the [doc](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction) for  more better visibility.

Now [Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial) is a very scalable, fault-tolerant distributed computation system which can easily be integrated with any queueing (like Kafka) or databases (HDFS/Cassandra etc). So you can feed your messages to a storm cluster for further processing based on your requirement. There is something called [KafkaSpout](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-kafka) which does a seamless integration between storm and kafka.

You should also look at the [Kafka-hadoop loader](https://github.com/michal-harish/kafka-hadoop-loader) @github which creates `Hadoop Job for incremental loading messages from Kafka topics onto hdfs with multiple file output semantics`

Also as @Peter Klipfel said that:
 *you might want to look into something other than hadoop if you need streaming*
You can also check for other alternatives available like [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) ,works great with streaming data with a very low latency.

Comment: @ShlomiHassan If you go with kafka, there is a [linked-in camus -- project build specifically for kafka -> hdfs pipeline](https://github.com/linkedin/camus/wiki).

Comment: can i assit you about using camus with kafka?
i having truble using camus with my kafka 0.8 on hortonworks 2.0.6 distribution

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you are pulling the data and what you are trying to do with the data.

An alternative is to use IBM Streams where you can pull directly from social media streams and store to many different data store of your choice.

For example, you can use the streamsx.social toolkit from here:  https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.social  which allows you to pull tweets directly from an HTTP stream.

Once you get data into Streams, the product also provides many adapters that allow you to store the streaming data into datastore (e.g. HDFS using streamsx.hdfs, HBase using streamsx.hbase.)

I think another consideration is what kind of analytics are you doing with the social media data.  If you would like to analyze the social data in-stream before the data is stored, IBM Streams also provides a text toolkit that allows you to extract insight from the social data unstructured text.  You can analyze the data without really having to store it anywhere.

Hope it helps!